# Is there any way in superset to visualize a mixed charts in a sorted order of y -axis?

Tags: charts, visualization, open-source, apache-superset

I was seeing the mixed charts in Superset and was trying to see a way to visualise a chart in sorted order of y-axis. Even after a lot of googling and scrolling through docs I couldn't find a way to do it.
The least I got is that we can sort the charts on the basis of x-axis.
So , is there any way to visualise the elements of the mixed chart on the sorted order of y-axis.

If not , then please help me to get a way to understand how the charts are formed in Superset and what a files in the source code are involved in it ,so that I can contribute in it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWx68.png)

In the above image i want to show the chart in the descending order of the bars i.e. "count of messages" .